# Can you configure the default commit title generated when merging PR on github enterprise?

Tags: git, github, github-enterprise

I'm using github enterprise.

When I try to merge a PR, it generates this default merge commit title in the format of:

```
Merged pull request {issue key} from {HEAD branch name}
```

[image]

I want to customize it like:

```
{HEAD branch name} → {target branch name} ({issue key})
```

Can I configure this?